# axios GET request function export/ import in react

Tags: reactjs, axios

How do I export axios get request from separate .js file so I can use it in my main.js by importing i.e:

```
import { getNewQuote }  from './api'

class App extends Component {

  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      quote: []
    }
    this.handleNewQuote = this.handleNewQuote.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    getNewQuote();
  }

  handleNewQuote() {
    getNewQuote();
  }
   ...
```

My api.js looks like this:

```
export function getNewQuote(){
    axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com';
    axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Mashape-Key'] = "MY-API-KEY";
    axios.get('/?cat=famous&count=1')
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ quote: res.data })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
}
```

With this setup I'm getting an error in console:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
>       at api.js:8
>       at

I assume the issue is with:

axios getNewQuote export or getNewQuote call in componentDidMount

Any help?

Comment: `getNewQuote.call(this)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can return the promise from the axios request and then handle it in the calling function like

```
export function getNewQuote(){
    axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com';
    axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Mashape-Key'] = "MY-API-KEY";
    return axios.get('/?cat=famous&count=1')
}
```

And Using it like

```
componentDidMount() {
    getNewQuote().then(res => {
        this.setState({ quote: res.data })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      });
  }

  handleNewQuote() {
    getNewQuote().then(res => {
        this.setState({ quote: res.data })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      });
  }
```

or call the `getNewQuote` function using the Javascript [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method and passing the reference of `this` to it like

```
 componentDidMount() {
    getNewQuote.call(this)
  }

  handleNewQuote() {
    getNewQuote.call(this)
  }
```

Comment: Nice! thanks, Shubham. It works but I have no idea how. :) the getNewQuote.call(this) part  is confusing :)

Comment: Read this mdn documentation of `.call` to understand how it works https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call  :)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thanks for the reference you provided.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 3):

The above answer is absolutely correct, but what I want to focus is writing dry code, so this is how I do it.

```
import axios from 'axios';
class BaseService {
  constructor() {
    this.baseUrl = "/api";
  }

  getData(path) {
    let url = `${this.baseUrl}${path}`;
    return axios.get(`${url}`);
  }
}

export default (new BaseService()); // singleton object
```

This base service is now can be imported in other component or services.

```
import BaseService from './services/base.service.jsx';

class Home extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        data: []
    }

}

componentDidMount() {
    let path = '/users';
    BaseService.getData(path)
        .then(resp => {
            this.setState({data: resp.data});
        }); // handle errors if needed
}
```